# How to decorate function to a dynamic programming function in python

Tags: python, profiling, dynamic-programming, decorator, memoization

I am trying to write a decorator function which converts a pure recursive function with two arguments that uses a "divide and conquer" strategy to an equivalent but more efficient one using dynamic programming.
Note: it is designated to decorate two input functions.

The questions I have are:
How can it decorate two input functions?
Can I decorate the decorator (as I tried to do)?

This is what I have managed to do:

```
profile_results = {}
t = {}

 '''The profile function stores the following: the time taken by the function, the name of the function and the number of times it was called and stores these in the dictionary called *profile_results* '''

def profile(func):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.calls += 1
        name = func.__name__
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time() - t1
        t = (t2)
        my_tuple = (t,wrapper.calls)
        profile_results[name] = my_tuple
        return res
    wrapper.calls = 0
    return wrapper

#the dynamic function is the more efficient one and it is a decorator
@profile
def dynamic(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if args in t:
            return t[args]
        else:
            res = func(*args, **kwargs)
            t[args] = res
            return res
    return wrapper

#regular recursive function
@dynamic
@profile
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

This is what it prints out when I test it:

```
factorial(5)
print(t)
print (profile_results)
```

Output:

```
{(0,): 1, (1,): 1, (2,): 2, (3,): 6, (4,): 24, (5,): 120}
{'dynamic': (0.0, 1), 'factorial': (0.0, 6)}
```

The first output is correct but I am trying to profile it to see if the dynamic programming one is actually faster. However, it is showing the times as 0. Would I need to add a *time.sleep()* somewhere and where would I add it to correctly output the time (given that they are recursive functions)?

I am wondering if I am decorating it properly. I am trying to decorate the dynamic function which is a decorator as well. And I am trying to decorate the factorial function with both the dynamic and profile function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why are you decorating `dynamic` with `@profile`? You know how many times it's called, just count the `@dynamic`s.

Comment: I want to find the time that each takes so that I can check whether it is actually faster